# C# format string "# ### ###.##" missing zero when lower than one

Tags: c#, format

When using format string `"# ### ###.##"`, the displayed values are correct. However, when a number like `0.12` is to be displayed, I can see only the `,12` (the comma decimal character is used correctly because of the country settings).

(I tried to add zero to the beginning of the formatting string, but that fills the insignificant position by zeros.)

How should I modify the format string so that `0.12` would be displayed as `0,12`... preserving the big numbers grouped by 3, separated by spaces like `1 234 567,89`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leading `#` placeholders will not show a zero, to get a minimum zero, you need a format like this:

```
"# ### ##0.##"
```

An example like this isn't specifically described in the docs, but this is the relevant reference:

> **[The "0" custom specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the-0-custom-specifier)**
> The "0" custom format specifier serves as a zero-placeholder symbol. If the value that is being formatted has a digit in the position where the zero appears in the format string, that digit is copied to the result string; otherwise, a zero appears in the result string.
>
> *The position of the **leftmost zero before** the decimal point and the **rightmost zero after** the decimal point determines the range of digits that are **always** present in the result string.*

So when using [The "#" custom specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier) we only need to place a `0` at the *leftmost* position to determine the minimum length of digits that will  always be visible.

In your case you need a minimum of 1 digit to the left of the decimal place, so you put the zero in the digit immediately before the decimal place.

If you wanted the same format, with a minimum of degits before the decimal, then you could use a format like this:

```
"# ### 0##.##"
```

Then `0.12` would be formatted into this:

```
000.12
```

It is also important to note that in your current format there is no minimum number of decimal places, so the value `0.1` will look like this:

```
0.1
```

So if you wanted to always display 2 decimals, the minimum format would look like this:

```
"# ### ##0.#0"
```

With this format, a value of `0` will render as:

```
0.00
```

> It is worth noting that for a value of `0` and a format of `"#.##"`
> **no value will be rendered at all!**
> Because that format pattern does not specify that *any* zeros are required.

Comment: Thanks! When reading the documentation for "0" now, it is obvious. However, it was not obvious (for me) when not knowing the possibility. :)

Comment: Now that I read the documentation myself, it's not really clear, it is just one of those things that you don't learn until you get burned ;)

Comment: "If the value that is being formatted has a digit in the position where the zero appears in the format string, that digit is copied to the result string; otherwise, a zero appears in the result string." So, without the zero, no digit would be displayed in the discussed case. Because of that the zero is displayed. At least, this is my understanding. :)

Comment: Yes, so a format `"###.##"` on a value of `0` would actually show nothing at all. `#` only shows a value if the value is _necessary_ to express the number. But zero itself is a special case, it represents nothing... using `"0"` in the format forces a zero for that placeholder, even if there is no value to display (or the value is zero)